# How to write file to Android device from outside of activity?

Tags: android, serialization, android-activity, android-file, data-access

I have main activity where I'm creating a new object called fileSaver. I'm trying to sarialize object 'data' to file. FileSave has a method serialize() which creates file.

```
private String FILE_NAME = "file.dat";
FileSaver fileSaver = new FileSaver();
Data data = new Data();
data.setEmail("aaa@bbb.com");
fileSaver.serialize((Object) data,FILE_NAME);
```

The problem is that I can't create a file outside activity. When I try the same inside activity, it creates that file. I was experimenting with paths but without success. I know when the file is created from activity it is saved in /data/data/my_package_name/files but how to access that file from outside activity class?

Class FileSaver:

```
public class FileSaver {

public void serialize(Object objToSerialize,String fileName) {

    try {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(fileName));
        out.writeObject(objToSerialize);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Object : " + objToSerialize.getClass()
                + " serialized successfully");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error Saving Object to File :"
                + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Post your logcat..are you getting any error messages?and how do you intend to do it outside activity??

Comment: Logcat: 12-01 18:45:39.001: I/System.out(1621): Error Saving Object to File 

:/file.dat: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
12-01 18:45:39.029: W/System.err(1621): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file.dat: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: Object for serialization is created inside activity so I think it should work somehow.

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass context to outside java class and using the context, use this openFileOutput() method to create and write a file in android device memory

Comment: Can you please explain this a little bit or maybe put some part of a code? I'm not sure I understand. Thanks.

Comment: How to pass context when I call serialize method? fileSaver.serialize((Object) data,FILE_NAME, ??context??); I know for openFileOutput() method but how to use that method in another class. The problem for me is how to connect it to that context of activity? I can't find example anywhere. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the file in the SDCARD instead.

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+filename));
```

//here filename is your input filename in String and Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() gives you the SDCard directory.

Also make sure you add the **`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`** in the Android Manifest file

Comment: Thank you. This is good idea (I will try it) but my idea is to write that file to /data/data/my_apk_package_name/files where application has all permissions to store files. I'm trying to do something what kumaand suggested above but I'm not sure how to transfer context and then use that openFileOutput() method. I was googling that almost whole day but can't find some code example.